# MySQL get current + N previous months

Tags: mysql, sql, date, where-clause

I have a query which returns 3 months of results:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM table
    WHERE 
    DATE(created) >= DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
    ORDER BY created
```

I want to show the current and three months before it. 
Since today is 30/03/2020 it should show:

```
- March 2020 (current month)
- February 2020 (-1 month)
- January 2020 (-2 months)
- December 2019 (-3 months)
```

How can do I change my query achieve it with MySQL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following filter:

```
created >= date_format(current_date, '%Y-%m-01') - interval 3 month
```

Rationale:

- `date_format(current_date, '%Y-%m-01')` gives you the beginning of the current month
- you can then substract 3 months from that to get the beginning of the search period

Note that the filters applies directly to the stored date, without transformation: this will be more efficient than using a condition that involves a date function.

Comment: Doesn't this return $today - 3 months ? Which will result the start at 30 december ?

Comment: @GiedriusPirmasis: this gives you data from december 1st. If you want from the 30th of december, you can do: `created >= current_date - interval 3 month`.

Comment: Didin't see that date formatting is setting the day to the first. Neat trick, thanks!